# Couchbase configuring client programmatically

Tags: c#, sdk, driver, couchbase

I want to configure couchbase c# driver programmatically, without web/app.config.

It looks like, configuration does not allow Urls to be set.

```
var cfg = new CouchbaseClientConfiguration()
{
     Bucket = "a",
     Urls = new List<Uri> () { .... } // It's readonly
};
```

Do i have to hack client? Is there another simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this sample from documentation doesn't work?

```
var config = new CouchbaseClientConfiguration();
            foreach (var uri in uris)
            {
                config.Urls.Add(uri);
            }
            config.Bucket = bucketName;
            config.BucketPassword = bucketPassword;

            _cbc = new CouchbaseClient(config);
```